# zend relationships with select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I am new to zend. I have been asked to redevelop a website that was once written in plain PHP and put it into the zend framework.

I am having a lot of trouble with database relationships, I cant seem to get my head round defining and querying relationships.

I would like to find a Category. From that Category I would like to be able to find all the CategoryInfo associated with it, and be able to query/sort/limit that dataset.

Here are my models.

Categorys.php

```
<?php
  class Default_Model_Categorys extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
  {
      protected $_name = 'Categorys';
      protected $_primary = 'id';

      protected $_dependentTables = array('Default_Model_CategoryInfo');
 }
?>
```

CategoryInfo.php

```
<?php
class Default_Model_CategoryInfo extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'Category_Info';
    protected $_primary = 'id';

    protected $_referenceMap = array(
        'Categorys' => array(
            'columns' => array('cat_id'),
            'refTableClass' => 'Default_Model_Categorys',
           'refColumns' => array('id')
        )
      );
}
?>
```

CategoryController.php

```
<?php
  class CategorysController extends Zend_Controller_Action
  {
      public function indexAction()
      {
        /*
          this should redirect to all games
        */
          return $this->_forward("index", "games");
      }

      public function categoryAction()
      {
          /*
            shows a specific category
          */
          $id = (int) $this->_request->getParam('id');
          $category = new Default_Model_Categorys();
          $this->view->category = $category->fetchRow(
              $category->select()->where('id = ?', $id)
          );

          $categoryInfo = $this->view->category->findDependentRowset('Default_Model_CategoryInfo');

      }
  }
```

Firstly... am I doing anything wrong?

Secondly... how do I go about querying the dependent rowset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you're searching for a category by its primary key, it's simpler to use the `find()` method:

```
$id = (int) $this->_request->getParam('id');
$category = new Default_Model_Categorys();
$this->view->category = $category->find($id)->current();
```

Second, to restrict or sort dependent `Category_Info` rows, you can use a `Zend_Db_Table_Select` object as an optional parameter of `findDependentRowset()`.  Here's an example:

```
$select = $category->select()->where("info_type = 'PRICE'")
                             ->order("info_date")
                             ->limit(3);
$categoryInfo = $this->view->category->findDependentRowset(
    'Default_Model_CategoryInfo', null, $select);
```

Notice you can use any table object to create that select object.  Since the "`FROM`" clause for that select will be set by the `findDependentRowset()` method, you just add other clauses and then pass it in.

PS: You don't need to declare `$_dependentTables` at all, unless you're going to use cascading update or cascading delete via PHP code.  I recommend strongly *against* doing that -- it's far more efficient to let the RDBMS handle those cascading operations.

Likewise you should never have to declare `$_primary` if your database tables actually declare primary key constraints.  `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` knows how to inspect metadata to get the primary key column(s).

Comment: Glad to help!  I have edited the above to add the call the `current()` because `find()` always returns a rowset, not a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks correctly to me. You don't query a dependent rowset. It is a query itself and it returns a result set. Basically what it is doing is pulling all records related to the current row you are working with as defined by $_referenceMap. Once you execute findDependentRowset(), you can foreach over the results which will give you instances of *Zend_Db_Table_Row*. From there you can display the related data as needed.

Personally I don't use Zend_Db Relationships. It is much easier to just make a second model method to query what I need. Also, Zend_Db Relationships do not support *where* clauses, so just making a second query is much more flexible than relationships.