# Zend_Db relationships from diagram

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, table-relationships

I have the following tables:
[image]

Each with its own mapper:
`Product_Model_DbTable_Product`
`Product_Model_DbTable_Category`
`Product_Model_DbTable_ProdCategRelation`

I've seen [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454705/zend-relationships-with-select) [tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638622/modeling-objects-with-multiple-table-relationships-in-zend-framework) about how it's done, but I still don't get it.

---

This is what I currently have:

```
class Product_Model_DbTable_Product extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'product';
    protected $_dependentTables = array('Product_Model_DbTable_ProdCategRelation');
}

class Product_Model_DbTable_Category extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'category';
    protected $_dependentTables = array('Product_Model_DbTable_ProdCategRelation');
}

class Product_Model_DbTable_ProdCategRelation extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'product_category';
    protected $_referenceMap = array(
        'Product' => array(
            'columns' => 'pid',
            'refTableClass' => 'Product_Model_DbTable_Product',
            'refColumns' => 'id'
        ),
        'Category' => array(
            'columns' => 'cid',
            'refTableClass' => 'Product_Model_DbTable_Category',
            'refColumns' => 'id'  
        )
    );
}
```

And my experimental controller code (more or less working, but the method doesn't seem right; might as well go back to plain table-joining):

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $productObj = new Product_Model_DbTable_Product;
    $categoryObj = new Product_Model_DbTable_Category();

    $product = $productObj->fetchRow('id = 1');
    $productRelation = $product->findDependentRowset('Product_Model_DbTable_ProdCategRelation', 'Product')->current();

    $category = $categoryObj->fetchRow('id = ' . $productRelation->cid);
    $categoryInfo = $category->findDependentRowset('Product_Model_DbTable_ProdCategRelation', 'Category')->current();
}
```

---

**Can I fetch a product's category by using these relationships just by instantiating a product, not the whole bunch?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [findManyToManyRowset](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html#zend.db.table.relationships.fetching.many-to-many) for that purpose. So your code might be transformed to:

```
$product = $productObj->fetchRow('id = 1');
$categoryInfo = $product->findManyToManyRowset(
    'Product_Model_DbTable_Category',
    'Product_Model_DbTable_ProdCategRelation'
)->current();
```

Comment: But without `current()`, which will return only first row from rowset - I think, that OP want's them all, in case that product has multiple categories.

Comment: I assume my `$_dependentTables` and `$_referenceMap` are correct for this purpose.

Comment: @singles `current()` was only taken from the OP's original code. Though I agree, Product - Category is probably not a 1:1 relationship.